# Bootstrap-validator not displaying errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I have the following form that I want to use the [bootstrap-validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/register/researcher" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-toggle="validator" novalidate="true">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="v5VF4sgb0zOrxzAihpEhkezccUWHPpXO5CnnmIK7">
<div class="from-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required" name="name" type="text">
</div>
<br>
<div class="from-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" data-error="O email inserido é inválido." required="required" name="email" type="email">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="from-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" data-minlength="6" id="inputPass" required="required" name="password" type="password" value="">
    <span class="help-block">Senha de no mínimo 6 caracteres</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="from-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmar senha" data-match="#inputPass" data-match-error="Senhas inseridas são diferentes" required="required" name="password_confirmation" type="password" value="">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="from-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="CPF" required="required" name="cpf" type="text">
</div>
<br>
<div class="text-center">
    <input class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="submit" value="Enviar">
</div>                </form>
```

I'm importing the validator.js and somehow it's working (it disables the submit button) but no erros are shown when I test the form. Can you help me to find where I'm doing something wrong?

(Plus: I'm using the laravel HTML Form Facades to generate this form)

Comment: Use <div class="form-group">  but not the 'from-group'

Comment: Since this uses standard Bootstrap classes to validate form elements, Don't forget to use with default Bootstrap form structure including classes such as "form-group" and "form-control".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update the class `from-group` to `form-group`.
2. Init bootstrapValidator instance by the following code.

   ```
   $(function () {
       $("#your form id").bootstrapValidator();
   );
   ```

Comment: I don't know how i didn't see this. I was blind probably. hahaha Thank you.

Comment: Since this uses standard Bootstrap classes to validate form elements, Don't forget to use with default Bootstrap form structure including classes such as "form-group" and "form-control".